# Execute bash file from Python

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, python-envoy

I want to execute a shell script file from within Python. I am currently using Envoy to do this:

```
envoy.run('./scripts.sh')
```

But it throws me a `No such file or directory` error.

I am wondering, under which path is the above file executed? How can I make the above script run? It is located in the same directory as the Python script.

Comment: The problem can also be the shebang-line in your script.sh. Maybe it points to a wrong interpreter, this way you get the same error message. Just a thought…

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` is the shebang-line

Comment: OK, if `/bin/bash` exists, then you should look at `envoy`, I don't know about that package. Try a `envoy.run('pwd')` to check where you are.

Comment: Have you used `chmod` on the script already? I don't know exactly what `envoy` does but it might still possibly require that your script is in `$PATH`.

Comment: A wrong chmod setting (missing x-flag) would yield a "Permission denied".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program is executed in the current working directory as reported by `os.getcwd()`. For a command line program, its typically the directory you are in when you run the program. To run a command in the same directory as your python script, use the `__file__` variable to figure out where you are:

```
import os
import envoy

my_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
envoy.run('./scripts.sh', cwd=my_path)
```

Comment: Indeed, specifying the `cwd` to `envoy` **and** `chmod`-ing `scripts.sh` solved my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The error you are receiving may not necessarily be from python itself but your bash script as the error you posted also can be returned from bash itself..

```
-bash: ./asdf: No such file or directory
```

Does your shell script require arguments? Also, have you tried to execute your shell script directly and not via python?

Another thing I would recommend is to use the environment bash rather than full path as this is typically better suited for portability due to the variances in linux OS design..

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```